# Выкладываю ТГ бота на PythonAnywhere, выдаёт ошибку, помогите!

Tags: python, aiogram, pythonanywhere, aiogram-2.x

Я сделал ТГ бота-модератора, в PyCharm работает прекрасно! Но в PythonAnywhere вообще не запускается, сразу же выдаёт такую ошибку:

```
WARNING:aiogram:Goodbye!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 980, in _wrap_create_connection
    return await self._loop.create_connection(*args, **kwargs)  # type: ignore[return-value]  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1064, in create_connection
    raise exceptions[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1049, in create_connection
    sock = await self._connect_sock(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 960, in _connect_sock
    await self.sock_connect(sock, address)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 500, in sock_connect
    return await fut
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/selector_events.py", line 505, in _sock_connect
    sock.connect(address)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 139, in make_request
    async with session.post(url, data=req, **kwargs) as response:
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1167, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 562, in _request
    conn = await self._connector.connect(
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 540, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 901, in _create_connection
    _, proto = await self._create_direct_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1209, in _create_direct_connection
    raise last_exc
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 1178, in _create_direct_connection
    transp, proto = await self._wrap_create_connection(
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 988, in _wrap_create_connection
    raise client_error(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unreachable]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/main.py", line 29, in <module>
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 45, in start_polling
    executor.start_polling(
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 320, in start_polling
    loop.run_until_complete(self._startup_polling())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 646, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 372, in _startup_polling
    await self._welcome()
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/utils/executor.py", line 361, in _welcome
    user = await self.dispatcher.bot.me
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 30, in me
    setattr(self, '_me', await self.get_me())
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/bot/bot.py", line 233, in get_me
    result = await self.request(api.Methods.GET_ME, payload)
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/bot/base.py", line 236, in request
    return await api.make_request(await self.get_session(), self.server, self.__token, method, data, files,
  File "/home/ModForMaxSpeedCuber/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/aiogram/bot/api.py", line 142, in make_request
    raise exceptions.NetworkError(f"aiohttp client throws an error: {e.__class__.__name__}: {e}")
aiogram.utils.exceptions.NetworkError: Aiohttp client throws an error: ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host api.telegram.org:443 ssl:default [Network is unre
achable]
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Бот написан на aiogram 2.25.1, код ниже:

```
import config
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types
import logging
from filters import IsAdminFilter
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
bot = Bot(config.TOKEN)
dp = Dispatcher(bot)
dp.filters_factory.bind(IsAdminFilter)
@dp.message_handler(is_admin=True, commands=["ban"], commands_prefix="!/")
async def ban(message: types.Message):
    if not message.reply_to_message:
        await message.reply("Отправте эту команду в ответ на определённое сообщение")
        return
    await message.bot.delete_message(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, message_id=message.message_id)
    await message.bot.kick_chat_member(chat_id=config.GROUP_ID, user_id=message.reply_to_message.from_user.id)
    await message.reply_to_message.reply("Пользователь забанен!!!!")

@dp.message_handler()
async def bad_language(message: types.Message):
    if "****" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
    if "******" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
    if "****" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
    if "****" in message.text:
        await message.delete()
if __name__ == "__main__":
    executor.start_polling(dp, skip_updates=False)
```